# MySQL - How To Transpose Cells In One Column Based On Unique Values In Another Column?

Tags: sql, database, magento, group-by, pivot

I need to fetch all our product categories from Magento 1.9 database and present it in one row, showing 'product ID', 'product type', 'sku' and 'category path' (IDs and values) I managed to get to the point where all my categories for each product are returned in multiple rows. My current query is below:

```
SELECT 
    p.entity_id AS 'product_id',
    p.type_id AS 'product_type',
    p.sku,
    c.category_id,
    l.level AS 'category_level',
    l.path AS 'category_path',
    n.name AS 'category_name'
FROM
    mage_catalog_product_entity AS p
        JOIN
    mage_catalog_category_product_index AS c ON p.entity_id = c.product_id
        JOIN
    mage_catalog_category_entity AS l ON l.entity_id = c.category_id
        JOIN
    mage_catalog_category_flat_store_6 AS n ON n.path = l.path
WHERE
    c.store_id = '6' 
        AND l.path LIKE '1/14%'
        AND l.path NOT LIKE '1/14/207%'
        AND l.path NOT LIKE '1/14/12/25%'
        -- AND l.level > 1
ORDER BY p.sku , length(l.path)
```

It returns the following:

[image: current query result screenshot]

What I am trying to achieve is something like that:

[image: desired query result screenshot]

Or, ideally, CONCAT these columns into one

[image: ideal query result screenshot]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, attach results as text, not as screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You can pivot your resultset with conditional aggregation.

Starting from your existing query, here is on approach that groups by product id, product type and sku, and uses the category level to spread category names across columns:

```
SELECT 
    p.entity_id AS product_id,
    p.type_id AS product_type,
    p.sku,
    max(l.level) AS category_level,
    max(l.path) AS category_path,
    max(case when l.level = 1 then n.name end) AS level1_category_name,
    max(case when l.level = 2 then n.name end) AS level2_category_name,
    max(case when l.level = 3 then n.name end) AS level3_category_name,
    max(case when l.level = 4 then n.name end) AS level4_category_name
FROM
    mage_catalog_product_entity AS p
        JOIN
    mage_catalog_category_product_index AS c ON p.entity_id = c.product_id
        JOIN
    mage_catalog_category_entity AS l ON l.entity_id = c.category_id
        JOIN
    mage_catalog_category_flat_store_6 AS n ON n.path = l.path
WHERE
    c.store_id = '6' 
        AND l.path LIKE '1/14%'
        AND l.path NOT LIKE '1/14/207%'
        AND l.path NOT LIKE '1/14/12/25%'
GROUP BY product_id, p.entity_id, p.sku
ORDER BY p.sku
```

Side note: do not use single quotes for column aliases; while some databases may support that, the SQL standard states that single quotes are meant for literal strings. Use the proper quoting character for your database, or better yet use aliases that do not require quoting.

Comment: ok, thank you. This, however only returns one category for each product. In some cases product can belong to multiple categories. How can we output all category paths on separate rows?